# how to display data in one page from different database table

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql

i have database that having 2 table which is event , venue.
the event table hold eventTitle , eventID  and venueID.
the venue table hold venueID , venueName and location.
this is my sql query .

```
$sqlEvent = "SELECT * FROM te_events , te_venue ORDER by eventTitle
                WHERE te_events.venueID = te_venue.venueID
                 ";
```

but there is an error `u have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE te_events.venueID = te_venue.venueID' at line 2` 
what i want to do is display the venuename and location in the page by using php script.
after i remove 'where' clause, everything works find but the event is repeated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrong clause where sequence

```
"SELECT * FROM te_events , te_venue 
  WHERE te_events.venueID = te_venue.venueID
ORDER by eventTitle  ";
```

In a select  the where clasue is before the order by

Comment: @ChiShen  well if my answer (or one the answer)   are right please choose one and mark it as accepted ..

Answer (score 1):

```
$sqlEvent = "SELECT * FROM te_events , te_venue WHERE te_events.venueID = te_venue.venueID ORDER by eventTitle  ";
```